# Kernel density estimation vs Nearest neighbor density estimation

Tags: kernel-smoothing, k-nearest-neighbour, density-estimation

For a data set of size $N$ where the goal is to estimate the probability density function $p(x)$, the starting point of both methods is (following Section 2.5 in MLPT by Bishop)
\begin{align*}
p(x) = \frac{K}{NV},
\end{align*}
where $K$ is the number of data points that fall within an area of volume $V$ centered at the point $x$. Kernel density estimation then fixes the volume $V$ and counts the number of points $K$, while nearest neighbor estimation fixes $K$ and finds the corresponding volume $V$.

For both methods the estimate converges to the true value as $N\to\infty$, but what are the pros and cons of each method compared to the other?